# Upgrading a reference counted buffer to an atomically reference counted buffer

Tags: concurrency, atomic

I have a reference counted buffer. In one thread, I fill it up. Diddling the refcount and writing a bunch of data into it.

Now in theory, if the refcount is done when that's done, I can upgrade the buffer into something atomically refcounted safely, as long as people can only read from it. In pseudocode, this looks something like:

```
refcount = 1
write some data
refcount += 1
write some data
refcount -= 1
write some data

if refcount != 1:
  fail()

// do something here?

for i in range(0, 100):
    refcount.atomic_increment()
    spawn_thread({
      refcount.atomic_increment()
      read some data
      refcount.atomic_decrement()
      refcount.atomic_decrement()
    })
```

I suspect I need some sort of memory barrier to make sure all the buffer writes (and refcount writes!) retire before the other threads start to read. I want to avoid atomic ops while writing data into the buffer, and only do high-latency stuff inside the "do something here?" comment.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Thread spawning will do the necessary synchronization.